# Get the selected color from Colors listBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I'm trying to shows all colors in a `ListBox`. using that [example](http://stuff.seans.com/2011/02/14/creating-a-listbox-that-shows-all-predefined-wpf-colors/)

and here's the code

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="All Colors"
    Width="640" Height="480" >

    <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetType"
        ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Type}" x:Key="colorsTypeOdp">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <sys:String>System.Windows.Media.Colors, PresentationCore,
                Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
                PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35</sys:String>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>

        <ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{StaticResource colorsTypeOdp}"
        MethodName="GetProperties" x:Key="colorPropertiesOdp">
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource colorPropertiesOdp}}"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Path=Name}" Stroke="Black" Margin="4" StrokeThickness="1" Height="50" Width="81"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

I want to get the selected color from the `ListBox selectedItem` which is a `System.Windows.Media.Color`. But It always return null when I cast the selected Item to `Color`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `listbox.SelectedItem` is of type `System.Reflection.PropertyInfo`. What it's referencing is the static property of the `System.Windows.Media.Color` class that holds the selected color.

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop = (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo)listbox.SelectedItem;
Color color = (Color)prop.GetValue(null, null);
string colorName = prop.Name;
```

`color` is then the `System.Windows.Media.Color` that was selected, and `colorName` is the name of the property (such as `Azure` or `Aquamarine`).

Comment: @MoezRebai Thanks :). It took a bit of debugging and wondering what each object's `.ToString()` was telling me, but I'm glad I could help you out. Thanks for making a fun question to answer!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your XAML, you haven't given the listbox you are trying to get the value from a name. As such I'm not sure why the code to get the selected colour isn't throwing an error.

When I want to get a value from some form of ListView I do 2 things.

First add a property in the view model, or code behind to hold the selected colour.

```
Color selectedColor {get; set;}
```

Then change the start of you ListBox XAML slightly so the selected value is bound to this property. So your XAML would start like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource colorPropertiesOdp}}"
    SelectedValue={Binding selectedColor, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged"}
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
```

Then you should just be able to read the selected value from the 'selectedColor' property.